# Show / Hide DIVs with toggleSlide

Tags: jquery, html, slidetoggle

I am **showing/hiding** DIVs like this:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" class="showhide" source="one"> Show/Hide </a>
<div id="one"></div>

<a href="#" class="showhide" source="two"> Show/Hide </a>
<div id="two"></div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery('.showhide').live( 'click' , function () {
    source = $(this).attr("source");
    $( '#' + source ).slideToggle( 'slow' );
    return false;
});
```

[Above code is working for me](http://jsfiddle.net/nNS5Z/).

Now I want to ask 2 things:

- How can I change text **'Show/Hide'** to **Show** when Div is closed and **Hide** when DIV is open?
- How can I hide all these DIVs when page is loaded first time?

Any improvements in above code are also appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: my answer might be little bit abstract , let me know if you need more details ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `callback` function within the `slideToggle` to change the text according to the `:visible` selector.

As for hiding the `div`, with your current markup a simple `next().hide();` should solve that.

```
jQuery('.showhide').live( 'click' , function () {
    $(this).next().slideToggle( 'slow',function(){
        $(this).prev().text(function(){
         if ($(this).next().is(":visible")) return "Hide"; 
           else return "Show"; 
        });  
    } );
    return false;
}).next().hide();
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/pdcxs/

Answer (score 3):

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/svtTj/

```
<a href="#" class="showhide" data-source="one">Show</a>
<div class="showhide__box" id="one">Test one</div>

<a href="#" class="showhide" data-source="two">Show</a>
<div class="showhide__box" id="two">Test two</div>
```

Some styles to hide boxes after page loading:

```
.showhide__box {
    display: none;
}
```

A little upgraded js:

```
$('.showhide').live( 'click' , function () {
    var _target = $( '#' + $(this).data('source') );
    $(this).text( _target.is(':visible') ? 'Show' : 'Hide' );
    _target.slideToggle( 'slow' );
    return false;
});
```

Comment: If the DIV's are always going after links (there is nothing between them), then you of course can use .next() instead of getting DIV by id and get rid of data-source attribute.

Answer (score 2):

answer to one of your questions.

you can use document.ready to hide all on the page load

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // hide it here
});
```

or in the css use display none and apply that class

```
.class 
{
  display:none;
}
```

Definetly second approach is better.

you can use jquery.text to change the text conditionally

```
http://api.jquery.com/text/
```

in your code inside click , you can do something like this

```
$(this).text("your text") //
```